# Is there any word alternative for "compared to"?

Tags: phrases

I'd like to find an alternative for "compared to", in order to avoid repeating the same phrase in my scientific paper.

Is there any alternative for this expression?

Comment: Can you give the phrase context?

Comment: For example; Compared to the previous study, our results could not show the difference between A and B. The score for A was low  compared to their score.

Comment: In comparison with the previous studies...or,  If we juxtapose our results with the previous studies.

Comment: When results are different, *in contrast* is a good phrase to use: "In contrast to the previous study, our results did not show the difference..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vis-à-vis is a possibility. Literally, it means face to face, but it can also be used as an expression of comparison.

> "Vis-à-vis our previous study, our results could not show the difference between A and B. The score for A was low, compared to their [its?] score." (Is the referent of "their" "our previous study"? I'm not sure.)

Other possibilities include

> - In relation to our previous study . . .
> - In terms of our previous study . . .
> - Comparing our previous study with our current study . . .
> - Putting the two studies side by side, we found that . . .
> - In a comparison between the former study and the current study, we found that . . .

Answer (score 0):

- in comparison with (just another way of saying the same thing)

Answer (score 0):

"We were unable to confirm Joe's report of differences between... "

"In our hands, Joe's results were irreproducible, with differences between A and B limited to [less than two sigma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)."

Comment: What do you mean by "less than two sigma"?  Sigma means "summation", then, what is "two" about?

Comment: Sigma is the standard deviation of the data. "For particle physics, the sigma used is the standard deviation arising from a normal distribution of data, familiar to us as a bell curve. In a perfect bell curve, 68% of the data is within one standard deviation of the mean, 95% is within two, and so on." http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/2012/07/17/five-sigmawhats-that/

Answer (score 0):

Consider "[collate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/collate)."

> collate: to compare (texts, statements, etc.)in order to note points of agreement or disagreement.

E.g.

[Records will be stored and collated with other information collected at other times and places.](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=KMiSvaARmPkC&pg=PA202&lpg=PA202&dq=%22collated+with+other%22&source=bl&ots=RmVg6qazJB&sig=AcBJ9t1MC02YpCRX84DxmP_FjPE&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=3yRLU66rGqmx0QXfk4DgBA&ved=0CFQQ6AEwCTgU#v=onepage&q=%22collated%20with%20other%22&f=false)

Also, consider "set (or *pit*) against one another."

[Setting these figures against the stock of foreigners broken down by nationality reveals different degrees of attractiveness.](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=b58YI5F0nYAC&pg=PA405&lpg=PA405&dq=%22setting+these+figures+against%22&source=bl&ots=HNJF4FdaaS&sig=Ew8zXK_eKnmcMr4ps-87m1c5lFA&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=gilLU6XTH8a60QWb24CQDA&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22setting%20these%20figures%20against%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

"Versus" would work, but may be considered excessively formal and somewhat stilted.